# How can I display each file download progress in a progressBar?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the new class code after all changes I did :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using unfreez_wrapper;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WeatherMaps
{


    class ExtractImages
    {
        int count = 0;
        int length;
        string stringForSatelliteMapUrls = "http://www.sat24.com/";
        static int counter;
        UnFreezWrapper uf;
        List<string> imagesSatelliteUrls;
        List<string> imagesRainUrls;
        string localdir;

        // Instance with one List and Files and Animation
        public ExtractImages(List<string> mapToRead, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }

        // Instance with more then one List and Files and Animation
        public ExtractImages(Queue<DownloadData> downloadQueue, List<string> FirstTags, List<string> LastTags, List<string> Maps, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
    {
        localdir = LocalFileDir;
        counter = 0;
        imagesSatelliteUrls = new List<string>();
        imagesRainUrls = new List<string>();
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++)
        {
            imagesSatelliteUrls.Add("Group " + (i + 1));
            string startTag = FirstTags[i];
            string endTag = LastTags[i];
            startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag);
            while (startIndex > 0)
            {

                endIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                string t = Maps[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
                position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag, position);

            }
                string imageSatelliteUrl = imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].StartsWith("Group"))
                {
                    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].StartsWith("http://"))
                    {
                        imagesSatelliteUrls[i] = "http://" + imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                        imageSatelliteUrl = imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                    }
                    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].Contains("href"))
                    {
                        downloadQueue.Enqueue(
                            new DownloadData(
                                new Uri(imageSatelliteUrl),
                                UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + i.ToString("D6")
                            )
                        );
                    }
            }
        }
    }

        public class DownloadData
        {
            public Uri DownloadUri;
            public string TargetPath;

            public DownloadData(Uri downloadUri, string targetPath)
            {
                this.DownloadUri = downloadUri;
                this.TargetPath = targetPath;
            }
        }
```

Since in the variable List I have each some index a string "Group" I had to add this filters.
Also the links in the imageSatelliteUrl List are not starting with http:// so I added this filter too but I'm not sure if its good way.

In Form1 I did:

In the top of Form1 I did:

```
private WebClient _webClient = null;
private readonly Queue<ExtractImages.DownloadData> _downloadQueue = new Queue<ExtractImages.DownloadData>();
ExtractImages ei;
```

In the constructor of Form1 i did:

```
InitializeWebClient();
```

Then in the DoWork event of the backgroundworker in Form1 i did:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (_downloadQueue)
            {
                ei = new ExtractImages(_downloadQueue, StartTags, LastTags, Maps, localFilename, UrlsPath);

                if (_downloadQueue.Count > 0)
                    foreach (ProgressBar pb in progressbars)
                    {
                        if (pb.Tag == null)
                        {
                            ExtractImages.DownloadData dd = _downloadQueue.Dequeue();
                            pb.Tag = dd;
                            _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(
                                dd.DownloadUri,
                                dd.TargetPath,
                                pb
                            );

                            if (_downloadQueue.Count == 0) break;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Then in Form1 i added this method:

```
private void InitializeWebClient()
        {
            _webClient = new WebClient();
            _webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompletedCallback;
            _webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressCallback;
        }
```

And in the end added this two events:

```
private void DownloadCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                //... download cancelled...
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //... download failed...
            }

            ProgressBar pb = e.UserState as ProgressBar;

            lock (_downloadQueue)
            {
                if (_downloadQueue.Count == 0)
                {
                    if (pb != null) pb.Tag = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    ExtractImages.DownloadData dd = _downloadQueue.Dequeue();
                    if (pb != null) pb.Tag = dd;
                    _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(
                        dd.DownloadUri,
                        dd.TargetPath,
                        e.UserState
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        private void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProgressBar pb = e.UserState as ProgressBar;
            if (pb != null) pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

But what it does is downloading one file I used a breakpoint then it stop or not continue to download and I don't see anything in the progressBars.

EDIT**

The method ExtractImages as it is now:

```
public ExtractImages(Queue<DownloadData> downloadQueue, List<string> FirstTags, List<string> LastTags, List<string> Maps, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
        {
            localdir = LocalFileDir;
            counter = 0;
            imagesSatelliteUrls = new List<string>();
            imagesRainUrls = new List<string>();
            int startIndex = 0;
            int endIndex = 0;
            int position = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++)
            {
                imagesSatelliteUrls.Add("Group " + (i + 1));
                counter++;
                string startTag = FirstTags[i];
                string endTag = LastTags[i];
                startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag);
                while (startIndex > 0)
                {

                    endIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
                    if (endIndex == -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    string t = Maps[i].Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + endTag.Length);
                    imagesSatelliteUrls.Add(t);
                    position = endIndex + endTag.Length;
                    startIndex = Maps[i].IndexOf(startTag, position);

                }
                    string imageSatelliteUrl = imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                    if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].StartsWith("Group"))
                    {
                        if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].StartsWith("http://"))
                        {
                            imagesSatelliteUrls[i] = "http://" + imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                            imageSatelliteUrl = imagesSatelliteUrls[i];
                        }
                        if (!imagesSatelliteUrls[i].Contains("href"))
                        {
                            downloadQueue.Enqueue(
                                new DownloadData(
                                    new Uri(imageSatelliteUrl),
                                    UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + counter.ToString("D6")
                                )
                            );
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: WebClient provides the DownloadProgressChanged event for this purpose - use it. Note that using this event only makes sense if you use the *Async methods provided by WebClient.

Comment: What is your code showing now?

Comment: hasan nothing. The progressBars are empty. Its only downloading the files in the new class method thats it. For now im not showing anything yet.

Comment: I changed the client.DownloadFile to Async:  Uri uri = new Uri(imagesSatelliteUrls[x]);
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri,
                                            UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + x.ToString("D6")); now i need to pass the progress of the download files to the progressBars.

Comment: Ok i will update my question with what i did now with the webclient !

Comment: Okay. You have 8 progress bars, right? So, i assume it would make sense to have only 8 downloads in parallel. However, in your code i see that you start all available downloads at once. How would you like to deal with a situation where you have more than 8 downloads?

Comment: elgonzo then no i want to make only 8 downloads in parallel. How do i do it in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: To keep my answer readable, i omitted any kind of exception handling. In your real code, however, you **MUST** take care of exception handling and situations involving failed or interrupted downloads!

To have 8 parallel downloads showing their progress in the respective 8 progress bars, you can only begin with 8 active downloads, any further existing download jobs are considered pending. When one of the active downloads finishes, another one of the pending download jobs will be started while associating it with the progress bar that was used for the finished download. (The code examples given here are done in a way to operate with any number of progress bars, not just only with 8.)

All pending download jobs will be stored in a queue. To start a download, a download job is taken out and removed from the queue.

```
private readonly Queue<DownloadData> _downloadQueue = new Queue<DownloadData>();
```

(Note the `private readonly`, which allows using this object as a synchronization object, as explained later.)

*DownloadData* is a simple type that contains all necessary information for each download job.

```
public class DownloadData
{
    public Uri DownloadUri;
    public string TargetPath;

    public DownloadData(Uri downloadUri, string targetPath)
    {
        this.DownloadUri = downloadUri;
        this.TargetPath = targetPath;
    }
}
```

Now, how is this queue being filled? The code essentially exists already in your ExtractImages class. But instead of filling the two lists *imagesSatelliteUrls* and *imagesRainUrls*, the queue will be filled instead:

```
public static void AddImageDownloadsToQueue(Queue<DownloadData> downloadQueue, List<string> FirstTags, List<string> LastTags, List<string> Maps, string LocalFileDir, string UrlsDir)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Maps.Count; i++)
    {
        string imageSatelliteUrl = ... // compose URL for satellite image

        downloadQueue.Enqueue(
            new DownloadData(
                new Uri(imageSatelliteUrl),
                UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + x.ToString("D6")
            )
        );

        string imageRainUrl = ... // compose URL for rain image

        downloadQueue.Enqueue(
            new DownloadData(
                new Uri(imageRainUrl),
                UrlsDir + "RainImage" + x.ToString("D6")
            )
        );
    }
}
```

With the method for filling the queue in place, it just needs to be called and eventually the queue being processed. Processing of the download queue happens at two occasions/in two places: (1) another download item has to be started if one of the active downloads is finished, and (2) initially starting a number of downloads according to the number of available progress bars (=download slots).

The former will be covered a bit later. The latter, together with calling the *AddImageDownloadsToQueue* method will happen in *backgroundWorker1_DoWork*:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    lock(_downloadQueue)
    {
        AddImageDownloadsToQueue(_downloadQueue, StartTags, LastTags, Maps, localFilename, UrlsPath);

        if (_downloadQueue.Count > 0)
            foreach (ProgressBar pb in progressbars)
            {
                if (pb.Tag == null)
                {
                    DownloadData dd = _downloadQueue.Dequeue();
                    StartDownloadWithProgressBar(dd, pb);

                    if (_downloadQueue.Count == 0) break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

You will notice three things here. First, the usage of **lock** to synchronize access to the download queue, avoiding potential concurrent accesses and race conditions. Note, that using *_downloadQueue* as lock object is safe and only safe because it is declared as `private readonly`.

Second, a test **if (pb.Tag == null)** is done. The ProgressBar's Tag property is being (ab)used here as a flag to indicate whether the progress bar is already in use for a download or not. If its value is null, it means it is not in use. Any other value (non-null) means, it is currently used for a download. Assuming that you will likely queue up download items in several chunks, this approach ensures that always all available progress bars are being used, no matter when exactly new download items are added to the queue.

The third and most important is the method *StartDownloadWithProgressBar*. This method sets up a WebClient object and starts the download.

```
private void StartDownloadWithProgressBar(ExtractImages.DownloadData downloadData, ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadCompletedCallback;
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressCallback;

    ActiveDownloadJob adJob = new ActiveDownloadJob(downloadData, progressBar, wc);
    progressBar.Tag = adJob;
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(
        downloadData.DownloadUri,
        downloadData.TargetPath,
        adJob
    );
}
```

Although WebClient.DownloadFileAsync is being used for downloading files, one single WebClient object cannot handle multiple concurrent downloads. Hence each download needs its own WebClient instance. Two callbacks take care of the WebClient's DownloadFileCompleted and DownloadProgressChanged events. These callbacks will be covered a bit later.

An *ActiveDownloadJob* object is created which keeps track of the download job and its associated ProgressBar and WebClient (although the sample code outlined below doesn't require access to the WebClient again, it might be practical for future extensions to have a reference of the WebClient instance at hand).

The *ActiveDownloadJob* is assigned to the progress bar's *Tag* property, which is done to indicate that the progress bar is in use. Also, the *ActiveDownloadJob* object is passed as *UserToken* parameter to the DownloadFileAsync method. This is done so the callback methods will know which progress bar to manipulate when called by the (ongoing) download.

ActiveDownloadJob is a very simple class:

```
    class ActiveDownloadJob
    {
        public DownloadData DownloadData;
        public ProgressBar ProgressBar;
        public WebClient WebClient;

        public ActiveDownloadJob(ExtractImages.DownloadData downloadData, ProgressBar progressBar, WebClient webClient)
        {
            this.DownloadData = downloadData;
            this.ProgressBar = progressBar;
            this.WebClient = webClient;
        }
    }
```

The callback method for a download being completed (*DownloadCompletedCallback*) has to take care about two things: checking for cancelled/failed downloads and start the next download job in the queue.

```
private void DownloadCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
         ... download cancelled...
    }
    else if (e.Error != null)
    {
         ... download failed...
    }

    ActiveDownloadJob adJob = e.UserState as ActiveDownloadJob;
    ProgressBar pb = (adJob != null) ? adJob.ProgressBar : null;

    lock (_downloadQueue)
    {
        if (_downloadQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            if (pb != null) pb.Tag = null;
        }
        else
        {
            DownloadData dd = _downloadQueue.Dequeue();
            StartDownloadWithProgressBar(dd, pb);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that access to the queue is synchronized by locking to the same synchronization object as happened in the method *backgroundWorker1_DoWork*. Furthermore, note how this method acquires the *ActiveDownloadJob* object instance of the download. Remember that the *ActiveDownloadJob* object was being passed as **UserToken** parameter to the *DownloadFileAsync* method? Here it surfaces again.

If there are no further download jobs in the queue, the *Tag* property of the progress bar is set to null to indicate the ProgressBar being free and available again, otherwise a new download job will be taken from the queue and started by calling *StartDownloadWithProgressBar*. StartDownloadWithProgressBar will set the progress bar's *Tag* property to the *ActiveDownloadJob* object of the new download.

No matter which case, it is always ensured that the *ActiveDownloadJob* object of the finished download is removed from the progress bar's Tag property, and thus it and the WebClient kept within will eventually be GC'ed.

Although we are almost finished, there is still some piece missing: The progress bar needs to be updated during the download. This happens in the callback method for the download progress:

```
private void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ActiveDownloadJob adJob = e.UserState as ActiveDownloadJob;
    if (adJob != null && adJob.ProgressBar != null)
        adJob.ProgressBar.Invoke((Action) (() => adJob.ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
}
```

*DownloadProgressCallback* obtains the ProgressBar object belonging to the download in the similar manner as *DownloadCompletedCallback* does.

If you need to know when all downloads are finished, here is a hint: If the queue is empty and no downloads are active, then all downloads have been finished (or, there were no downloads to begin with...)

Comment: Elgonzo i just updated my question now added the code i did in the new class and in Form1. In the new class i see that the List imageSatelliteUrl contain 260 links as it suppose to be. But i used a breakpoint on this line downloadQueue.Enqueue(
                                new DownloadData(
                                    new Uri(imageSatelliteUrl),
                                    UrlsDir + "SatelliteImage" + i.ToString("D6")
                                )
                            ); i click continue it keep stop there un till the List is filled to 260 links and thats it.

Comment: After the List is filled after 7 itertions/loops filled with 260 links thats it . It back to the program and nothing happen. I dont see anything on the progressBars.

Comment: Is Webclient.DownloadFileAsync actually being called? Does it throw an exception perhaps?

Comment: The Webclient.DownloadFileAsync on form1 does called but i see now that the uri inside lead to no exist page. And that the files that are was downloaded on my hard disk are okb size. For example this is a uri: http://image2.ashx/?region=eu&time=201310291045&ir=true&type=ra&ra=true

Comment: I will check it . How to download this links. Other are ok but this ones are not working. I will open a new question for it. Maybe thats the problem why the progressBars and nothing is not working ?

Comment: Doron, you MUST do exception handling and take care of failed/cancelled downloads, as i said in the first sentence in my answer. The 'right' way to do this really depends on what you/your application want to happen in case of such error situations. It is not so much a question for other people, but rather a question to yourself: "How should my program react if a download doesn't work?"

Comment: Doron, do you see the progress bar for working, proper URLs? (The URL you mentioned is incomplete.)

Comment: elgonzo no. I removed the problem url and its tags and in Form1 im getting an exception another one : WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations on the Webclien.DownloadFileAsync.

Comment: elgonzo here is a link to my project 97kb size only maybe you can take a look at it: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!314&authkey=!AEwZjgsCI_6MPa8

Comment: In the constructor of form1 i removed for the test the tags of the html file that itsl inks didnt download before also im not downloading this html file so it wont extract the file from it again. So now Maps and the tags Lists contain 7 indexs and in the new class i see the links and i tested them on chrome i can surf and see the links images. But still getting exception now in Form1 when starting the backgroundworker .

Comment: On the _webClient.DownloadFileAsync in Form1 line i see that the variable dd contain a valid working uri and under it a file name SatelliteImage000003 and on my hard disk i see saved file called SatelliteImage000002 and this file is 0kb size. No SatelliteImage000000 or SatelliteImage000001 and the progressBars are not working at all.

Comment: Look at the link of my skydrive maybe you can download my project and test it.

Comment: Doron, i'll look into your code. While i remember having used one WebClient instance for multiple downloads running at the sime time, my memory might have been fooling me. I will look into this, too...

Comment: elgonzo yes thanks the problem is that there is one webclient trying to download 8 files at once. I will wait for you to take al ook at it. Thanks.

Comment: Doron, i have updated my answer. Note that i have introduced a new method **StartDownloadWithProgressBar** and type **ActiveDownloadJob**, and discarded **_webClient** and the **InitializeWebClient** method. I haven't tested yet by myself (somehow your VS2012 project compiles, but doesn't like to run on my VS2010 setup, so i will need to tinker a bit there), but when i do and find some bugs, then i will silently update my answer...

Comment: elgonzo ok now its downloading 4 files and i see the progress in 4 progressBars. But its downloading only 4 files parallel and when they finish its not continue to the next files. Another thing on my hard disk i see 4 files : SatelliteImage000002, 000003, 000004, 000005 its not starting from 000000 or 000001 but starting from 000002

Comment: Doron, i looked at you project -- ExtractImages puts only 4 downloads in the queue. There are no further downloads.

Comment: I cant figure out yet whay the ExtractImages is not working. I wanted to extracrt from each Map which is a html file content the links from it. And add before each Map(links) a string like"Group 1" then "Group 2" and so on. And then so it will download lets say 6 files parallel at the same time one file from each group . And if one file is ended to download the next file will be download from the same group the file was ended to be downloaded. And so on.

Comment: Just uploaded my question in the bottom the ExtractedImages method how it is now i cant figure out how to do it. Strange.

Comment: Doron, put this rather in a separate question, and then let's follow up there. This here becomes to convoluted, and other visitors might not know what was the question and the belonging answer anymore :)

Comment: Actually, before asking a new question, use a debugger to see what your ExtractedImages method is doing exactly for every download link you expect...

Comment: elgonzo i created a new question about the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666206/why-the-method-extractimages-is-not-working